# Aggregating days into weeks in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, aggregate

Has anyone got any tips for this problem i'm facing. Its not complex, but there might be a cleaner way to do it in Core Data.

I have a table of data (or managed object) with date and a value. I present this data normally showing each day and the value for each day.

I want to group this in weeks, so aggregate all rows that have a week of a certain number.

Example: my data is currently display like this

- Aug 5 |    5
- Aug 4 |    18
- Aug 3 |    8
- Aug 2 |    3
- Aug 1 |    10
- Jul 31 |   2
- Jul 30 |   1
- Jul 29 |   7
- Jul 28 |    6

etc etc

I want to display it like so:

- Week 24 |  47
- Week 23 |  13
- Week 22 |  20

etc etc

I'm already using an NSFetchedResultsController, and would like to continue to use this if possible. I think this is where the difficulty lies. If i was just presenting a UITableView and a NSArray of data, this would be easy to add up my values and present the data.

However, NSFetchedResultsController seems to be tied to fetching results (obviously), so I guess I want to aggregate this data using a fetch so that I can hook it right into my table view as I do with the raw data.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: to further clarify, you want one table view cell to contain information about one week, and your data is kept per day?

Comment: Thats correct. Usually 1 cell is 1 day, but i want 1 cell to contain 1 week.     I don't own the data, this is how I retrieve it - so i have no control over it other than manipulating once i retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, but sort of an ugly way. But it works, and I needed to get it working quick...

Because I wanted to continue to use my FetchedResultsController, and all the architecture I'd created to hook it up to my view controllers, it seemed easier to have distinct entities for my Weeks and Months.

I know it goes against data storage principles by storing data that could be computed, but it was relatively easy to do.

I have my UsageDay managed object, which is the majority of the data. I then have a UsageWeek and UsageMonth object.

When I store a UsageDay object, from its date ivar, I calculate its weekOfYear and monthOfYear (and year) for both UsageWeek and UsageMonth.

UsageWeek contains: weekOfYear, year, and an NSSet of the UsageDay objects it contains
UsageMonth contains: monthOfYear, year, and an NSSet of the UsageDay objects it contains.

I can then easily get a list of all UsageWeek's, which has a set of 7 UsageDay objects - on which i call [usageWeek valueForKeyPath:@"usageDaySet.@sum.value"] - which gives my the total. Works fine.

Feel free to openly criticize this design - I'm expecting it!!!

Answer (score 0):

my dear this is a really big deal. Just think of the many many different calendars which the user may have. But nonetheless the date is saved as a timestamp since 1970 in seconds. You can try to calculate with that `coreDataDate % (86400*7) // seconds per day * 7 days`.
By calculating with modulo it will automatically group by seven days. But remember there are many cases to preconceive for example the winter/summer time change in some countries.

Comment: you really don't want to be doing any arithmetic on dates, that's what `NSDate` and [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCalendar) were meant to abstract away from you.  Check out `+currentCalendar` and `-components:fromDate:`.

Comment: my dear, the only calendars I would have to deal with are the languages I support in my app. I'm not writing a framework here.

Comment: the calendar will handle the edge cases for you (if that's important), leap years, daylight savings time, etc

Comment: yeah, I watched the 'calendars' wwdc 2011 video a few weeks ago. Learned quite a lot about what the calendar api provides....recommended watching, especially if 86400 appears after a search of your code!

Answer (score 0):

(preface: there are no "tables" in CoreData)

If you modify the data model to provide a derived attribute (it can be in the custom subclass, and needs not be modeled) that defines the week.  Perhaps `weekOfYear`.  You'd then want to group the sections by week and year.

Comment: "There are no tables" - you're right, - apart from it is backed by a database, sqllite - where there are tables, and it's presented using a UITableView - which obviously is a table. So conceptually there are no tables in core data - but in reality, it is tabular data.  I'll don't particulary want it grouped into sections - but the data aggregated - i'll edit my post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into creating a method that uses a combination of NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to find the days that belong to a week and then pull the days of that week using NSPredicate with a BETWEEN statement.  This will be easier if the dates are in NSDate format but if not, you can easily convert.

I used something very similar when I had to pull all the days of a week out of a Core Data store for a time card app.

Comment: Yup, i'm using these. See my own answer. It seems like I'm doing it awkwardly though.